# How can I use useState to modify an array in order to a constant in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have an array object value in a constant called room.

```
room = [
    {name: "buger", placeId: 252}
    {name: "pack", placeId: 253}
    {name: "apple", placeId: 254}
    {name: "peach", placeId: 255}
]
```

At this time, I want to change the value of name in the room by using the onChangeroom function whenever I write a character in TextInput.

So, when I run setRoom in the onChangeRoom function and attach ["name"], an Unexpected Token error appears.

How do I change my code to change the name of the room?

Below is my code.

```
const [room, setRoom] = useState(
targetFarm.children.map((v) => ({ name: v.name, placeId: v.placeId }))
)


const onChangeroom = useCallback((index) => (text) => {
    setRoom({ ...room, [index]["name"]: text });      // << this might cause error
}, []);


{targetFarm.children.map((item, index) => {
    return (
<TextInput
style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange' }}
value={room[index]["name"]}
onChangeText={onChangeroom(index)}
/>

...
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `index` in `map` function. After you've got an index, then you can update.

Let me show an example:

```
const [room, setRoom] = useState([
    ...targetFarm.children
]);

const onChangeroom = useCallback((index, text) => {
    
    setRoom(room.map((pr, i) => {
    if(i === index) {
      return {
        ...pr,        
        name: text
      }
    }
    else return pr;
  }))
}, []);
```

Comment: `[...room].map()` can be simplified to `room.map()` to avoid duplicating the array twice.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal thank you for the advice! Please, see my updated reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing both `index` and `text` to `onChangeRoom(text, index)`
And modify the `useCallback` hook to look like this (notice that both arguments are passed to the second function inside the hook):

```
const onChangeroom = useCallback(() => (text, index) => {
    setRoom({ ...room, [index]["name"]: text });
}, []);
```

Let me know it this works for you.

Comment: it doesn't work